# When I try to install Wamp with MySQL 5.7.30 it shows error mysqld.exe application error

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I was trying installing WAMP server with MySQL 8 and it works completely fine. But since I have to work on a project that runs on MySQL version 5.7, I tried installing it as an add on. But it is showing the error "mysqld.exe" - Application Error. I've installed all the VC packages for both 64bit and 32bit. Mine is an Azure windows 10 virtual machine of 64bit architecture. The apache and mariadb are working fine. The issue is only with MySQL [image showing errror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fands.png) .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please check the Windows Event log for more meaningful errors